# Scroll to the bottom of the navbar page

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Let say I have below `Shiny-app` -

```
library(markdown)

ui =
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(id = "Navbar", "Navbar",
                tabPanel(tabName = "Tab1", "Tab1", 
                          div(style = "height: 2000px; width: 1500px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll;",
                                                div(style = "height: 3000px; width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;",
                                                    HTML("A")))),
                tabPanel(tabName = "Tab2", "Tab2",
                          div(style = "height: 2000px; width: 1100px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll;",
                                                div(style = "height: 3000px; width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;",
                                                    HTML("B"))))
              )
)

server =
function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now I want when user click the `2nd tab` for the first time, `app` should automatically scroll down to `bottom` of both the container page and `div`. I am thinking to have some sort of smooth scrolling.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Based on the suggestion from @dcruvolo on adding data-name, I have modified the `app` -

```
library(shiny)
ui <- tagList(
    navbarPage(
        id = "Navbar", "Navbar",
        tabPanel(
            tabName = "Tab1", "Tab1",
            div(
                style = "height: 2000px; width: 1500px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll;",
                div(
                    style = "height: 3000px; width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;",
                    HTML("A")
                )
            )
        ),
        tabPanel(
            tabName = "Tab2", `data-name` = "Tab2", "Tab2",
            div(
                style = "height: 2000px; width: 1100px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll;",
                div(
                    style = "height: 3000px; width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;",
                    HTML("B")
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    tags$script(
        "
        // select desired tab link
        $('a[data-name=\"Tab2\"]').bind('click', function(event) {

            // scroll to bottom of page
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
            }, 500);

            // remove
            $(this).unbind('click');
        })
        "
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Unfortunately, scrolling effect is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to the bottom of the page by creating an event listener that runs when "Tab 2" is clicked. Select the desired element and extract the value of the `scrollHeight` property, and then pass it into jquery's `scrollTop()`. (I've attached it to the `document.body`, but you can substitute it for any element you like.)

Here's the example app using the on click event. I added it using `tags$script`. To attach the event to another tab, substitute `data-value` with the name of the desired tab.

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- tagList(
    navbarPage(
        id = "Navbar", "Navbar",
        tabPanel(
            tabName = "Tab1", "Tab1",
            div(
                style = "height: 2000px; width: 1500px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll;",
                div(
                    style = "height: 3000px; width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;",
                    HTML("A")
                )
            )
        ),
        tabPanel(
            tabName = "Tab2", "Tab2",
            div(
                style = "height: 2000px; width: 1100px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll;",
                div(
                    style = "height: 3000px; width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;",
                    HTML("B")
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    tags$script(
        "
        // select desired tab link
        $('a[data-value=\"Tab2\"]').bind('click', function(event) {

            // scroll to bottom of page
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight
            }, 500);

            // remove
            $(this).unbind('click');
        })
        "
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks. This runs every time user click on 2nd tab. However I intended to have it only for first click. Is there any way to add session-info to achieve this?

Comment: See the updated code. I restructured the click event. It now uses `bind` and  `unbind`. (I'm not sure if `on`/ `off` is a better approach. I haven't used jQuery in a while.)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to call this JS by tabName = "Tab2" instead of data-value = Tab2? For my case, calling by tabName would be more appropriate. I tried with a[data-name=\"Tab2\"]') but it is not working

Comment: There isn’t an auto-generated `data-name` attribute. By default, shiny generates the attribute `data-value` using value from `tabPanel(title = “data value”, ...)`. You might be able to add custom data attributes to a tab panel by adding `data-name = “Tab2”` into the tabPanel function (Make sure data-name is wrapped in backticks). I haven’t tested it, but it could work.

Comment: There isn’t an auto-generated `data-name` attribute. By default, shiny generates the attribute `data-value` using value from `tabPanel(title = “data value”, ...)`. You might be able to add custom data attributes to a tab panel by adding `data-name = “Tab2”` into the tabPanel function (Make sure data-name is wrapped in backticks). I haven’t tested it, but it could work.

Comment: I have added new app based on your suggestion on adding data-name. Unfortunately, this did not work

Comment: I was unsure if it would. There are probably other javascript solutions, but  `data-value` is probably the best option as it’s a default attribute.